# Firebase Database in Unity - Child value into UI text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i just came across the firebase and thats seems to be exactly what I need. At the moment I am trying to implement it in my unity project but first I am just testing a bit to get used to it.

Can someone tell me how I can easily just receive the value of a child in my database and save it in a variable of my unity project? At the end I would like to display the Value in a UI Text. It doesn't need be really dynamic. The easier the better so I can be sure to understand it.

It tried it as follows:

```
variableXY.text = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference ("Databasename").Child ("Childname").GetValueAsync ().ToString ();
```

The result is, it displays the text : **System.Threading.Task.Task1 [Firebase.Database.Datasnapshot]**

Only the value is needed.

I would highly appreciate it if someone could help me out

Thanks a lot!

just to show my complete code right now which maybe makes something clearer.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;

public class DBManager: MonoBehaviour {

    public Text MA1Sensor1;
    public Text MA1Sensor2;

    void Start() {


        // Set up the Editor before calling into the realtime database.
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://unityar-6eb13.firebaseio.com/");

        // Get the root reference location of the database.
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference("MA1")
            .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;

    }

    void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
        if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
            Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log (args.Snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
        MA1Sensor1.text = FirebaseDatabase
            .DefaultInstance
            .GetReference ("MA1")
            .Child ("Zaehler")
            .GetValueAsync ()
            //.Result
            .ToString ();
        Debug.Log (MA1Sensor1.text);

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase SDK uses Tasks to return values to you asynchronously.
Check out [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#read_data_once) on how to retrieve a value.

You can also use Unity's "WaitUntil" if you are inside a Unity coroutine to make it simpler.  Note that you can use DataSnapShot.Value to get a parsed value or GetRawJsonValue() if you wanted to see the underlying Json.  In most simple scenarios, you'd want Value.  You'd use "GetRawJsonValue()" if you were using typed objects and Unity's Json serialization.

```
var getTask = FirebaseDatabase
   .DefaultInstance
   .GetReference ("MA1")
   .Child ("Zaehler") .GetValueAsync();

yield return new WaitUntil(() => getTask.IsCompleted || getTask.IsFaulted);

if (getTask.IsCompleted) {
  Debug.Log(getTask.Result.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous operations are basically `Task`s which should run in the background and be awaitable when needed.
Reason why your text is `System.Threading.Task.Task1[Firebase.Database.Datasnapshot]` is really simple.
Since you're calling `GetValueAsync()` it returns object of type `System.Threading.Task<Firebase.Database.Datasnapshot>` on which you tried to call `ToString()` method which results with getting typename.

To fix this you can add `Result` after `GetValueAsync()` which will wait for the result and then call `ToString()`.

*example :*

```
variableXY.text = FirebaseDatabase
                  .DefaultInstance
                  .GetReference ("Databasename")
                  .Child ("Childname")
                  .GetValueAsync ()
                  .Result // wait for the result of asynchronous operation
                  .ToString ();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your really fast answer.

Unfortunately it ends up crashing my unity all the time when I try to run in, with the Result command included. 
Any suggestion?

Because you said Asynchronous is for background operation, do you think its the right choice for my case? That command is placed in "Value Changed event" and it suppose to update the value. That value is going to change later probably every second and furthermore there should be 8 of them displayed. I want to display some sensor live da. What do you think about that?

Thank you again

Comment: I think it's the wrong choice when working with Unity. I would use synchronous call or use different thread to deal with database communication.

Comment: Yeah I thought so as well sometimes but its a part of an augmented reality and item detection program, so until now unity is necessary.

How would that work with a synchronous call?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I display the value of .GetRawJsonValue() in the UI Text that seems already quite good. Changes in the Database will be done immediately in the unity project. Couldn't I just take a part of that Json Value?

Right now it displays the following RawJson:

```
{"Program":1,"Zaehler":600}
```

Just putting the value of "Program"s Childvalue into variable A and "Zaehler"s Childvalue into variable B should work. I know it is pretty dirty, but for testing it just need to work right now. So, can I somehow just get access to a party of the RawJson?

Can't be thankful enough ;)